# UWP: How can I exclude GridView scrollbar from overlapping content?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I added a `GridView` component to an UWP `Page`, similar to this:

```xml
<Page>
  <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind CdList}">
  ...
  </GridView>
</Page>
```

When I change the window size, I notice that the `GridView`'s vertical scrollbar partially hides/overlaps the rightmost items in the `GridView` before `GridView` wraps the items appropriately:

[image: Canvas hidden by scrollbar]

Is there any `GridView` property available to have `GridView` wrap its items right *before* they are overlapped by the scrollbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main body of the `GridView` is composed of a `ScrollViewer` and an `ItemsPresenter` that displays item content. So the scroll bar belongs to the `ScrollViewer`, which is "covered" on the content information.

Since these two controls are not on the same level, there is no API for preventing the scroll bar from "overlapped" the content.

As a workaround, we can use `GridView.Padding` to reserve space for the scroll bar. Because in the default control template, the `Padding` property is bound to `ItemsPresenter`.

```xml
<GridView Padding="0,0,16,0">
    <!--Other code-->
</GridView>
```

*P.S. The default vertical scroll bar width is 16*